# New features introduced with HTML5

Tags: html

I haven't used HTML5 possibilities in my web applications because of browsers' poor support, but situation seems to become much better so I became really interested in its new cool features (even though many of them are only in a draft state today).
I already know about cool Web Sockets, WebGL and Canvas (with this stuff I can finally get rid of Flash!)
What are the new things in HTML5 that I should be aware of? (I mean new ways of web-programing not the particular tags) (the question was inspired by Google IO)

Comment: Have you considered a Googling for "HTML5" or looking at the Wikipedia page?

Comment: You should make this a community wiki, since there is no one correct answer.

Comment: I edited the title to make it seem less argumentative and subjective, as "coolest" alone would probably earn this a close vote. ;)

Comment: Adobe doesn't like HTML5. I've heard they sent a few assassins to the HTML5 team for a cup of tea... Fortunately, they like coffee.

Comment: @ceejayoz yes, I've already done so but I'm interested not in particular tags, but new ways of programing that's available with HTML5 (like p2p communication with WebSockets that I've mentioned)

Comment: @tsds Google and Wikipedia will reveal much more than mere tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [Dive into HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/).  It explains most of the features of HTML5 in a very illustrative way.  Database functionality and offline applications are two additional things you didn't mention.

Answer (score 1):

[Dive Into HTML5](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/) by Mark Pilgrim is a great resource for this.

Contents include:

- `<canvas>`
- `<video>`
- Geolocation
- Local Storage
- Offline applications
- New form features (placeholder, new types)